# Easyautocomplete js filtrar por dos campos

Tags: jquery, html, autocompletar

Necesito filtrar por mas de un campo , actualmente puedo filtrar solo por "name" pero tambien necesito poder filtrar por "code", no he encontrado en la documentación la forma de hacer esto , he intentado agregar mas de un "getValue" pero no encuentro la forma correcta de realizar esto gracias

he intentado reemplazar getValue por esto sin resultados:

```
getValue: function(element) {
    return $(element).find("name").text() + " " + $(element).find("code").text();
}

getValue: function(element) {
   return element["code"]["name"];
},
```

http://easyautocomplete.com/

```js
var options = {
  data: [{
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "code": "AF"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aland Islands",
      "code": "AX"
    },
    {
      "name": "Albania",
      "code": "AL"
    },
    {
      "name": "Algeria",
      "code": "DZ"
    },
    {
      "name": "American Samoa",
      "code": "AS"
    },
  ],
  getValue: "name",

  list: {
    match: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
};

$("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.themes.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>


<input id="provider-json" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de días de buscar encontre  la solución para filtrar por dos campos espero que les sirva saludos

```js
var options = {
  data: [{
      "name": "Afghanistan",
      "code": "AF"
    },
    {
      "name": "Aland Islands",
      "code": "AX"
    },
    {
      "name": "Albania",
      "code": "AL"
    },
    {
      "name": "Algeria",
      "code": "DZ"
    },
    {
      "name": "American Samoa",
      "code": "AS"
    },
  ],
  getValue: function(element) {
return element.name + " " + element.code;
},

  list: {
    match: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
};

$("#provider-json").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.themes.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>


<input id="provider-json" />
```